# Did Apple remove the "AppleScript handler" option in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mac, applescript, messages, high-sierra

I wanted to make a little script involving messages on my Mac and after some research I discovered it was indeed possible. The only problem is that the "AppleScript handler" option in Messages>Preferences>General is missing for me. [This very option is listed right on the Apple website under the High Sierra heading.](https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/general-preferences-icht20001/mac)

This is what I'm expecting:

[image: expected]

But this is all I see:

[image: actual]

For what it's worth I'm running **10.13.4 Beta (17E160e)**. Is it possible that this feature has been removed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Apple DID remove that feature in 10.13.4. I actually opened a case on this with Apple Support (I even referenced this page) and they got back to me today and informed me that it really has been removed from Messages.  The Apple representative suggested going to http://www.apple.com/feedback/ if I wanted to express my displeasure, but that was all he could do.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I did not contact Apple directly but this seems to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: I am not on High Sierra so I can't try this but, could we try copying the Messages Preferences Plist from and older build that did include this feature and see if we can get it back? Otherwise can we copy the entire Messages.app and try to figure out where the change was made?  I have done this with a couple apps in a different way.  I got the Game Center app from Mavericks on macOS Sierra.

Comment: In the end I found it was easier to just install and use Adium (https://adium.im/) because it gives back much of what is now missing in Messages and it is very configurable.  The only real downsides are that it looks a bit ugly in its default configuration (IMHO) but if you spend time configuring it, it can be made to look much better, and that it won't do iMessage chats because that's an Apple proprietary format.  So I have to run both Messages (for iMessage) and Adium (for the other protocols) but at least it all works. And running an Applescript when a new message is received IS an option.

Answer (score 4):

I have spoken with apple tech support senior advisor and they called me back and confirmed that the applescript handler option in messages has been removed in the latest operating system update 10.13.4. If you would like to send them feedback go to Apple.com/feedback and let them know your thoughts and that we would like the option back.