# SMS auto responder via Messages

Tags: macos

I have my Mac and iPhone linked so I can
 send and receive SMS via iMessage on the Mac. Is there a way, for instance a script, that I can use to send a predetermined response whenever an SMS comes in from a specific Cell number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto reply to text and/or iMessage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304944/auto-reply-to-text-and-or-imessage)—see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304944/auto-reply-to-text-and-or-imessage/327515#327515), but also note that Apple removed the Messages app AppleScript Handler option in macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, as discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/318230/did-apple-remove-the-applescript-handler-option-in-macos-high-sierra).